# losing jQuery lightbox popup

Tags: jquery, css, lightbox

I'm trying to move a section of code with links that pop up a lightbox to another place on the page. I need to do this with just javascript/jquery commands. I'm moving the div with id="winning-designs" to the div with id="intro-examples". Here's what I have:

$("#intro-examples").empty();

$("#intro-examples").html("< div id='winning-designs' class='product-section'>"+$("#winning-designs").html()+"< /div>");

My problem is that when I do this, the links in the html that are supposed to open in lightbox are not popping up the lightbox. They're just acting like normal links. Why am I losing this functionality? Thanks.

The spaces in the div tags are not actually there. For some reason I had to add them to get the divs to show up in this question.

Ok, I'm about to start crying if I can't do this!!! Here's the html I'm trying to affect:

```
    <li class="winning-design">

    <!-- thumb -->
    <a href="#" class="lightbox-trigger" title="View case study" data-lightbox-target="winning-design1-lightbox">
        <img src="/static/images/category-product-pages/logo-design/example1-thumb.png" width="268" height="160" />
        <p class="larger-link">View case study</p>
    </a>

    <!-- lightbox -->
    <div id="winning-design1-lightbox" class="lightbox winning-design-lightbox">
        <div class="lightbox-content">

            <div class="winning-design-info">
                <h3>Carplanet.com.au</h3>
                <p>Carplanet.com.au is an Australian based website that reviews new cars. They didn't have a predefined brand or color scheme in mind, so allowed designers to have complete artistic freedom for this logo.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li class="contest-stat">Paid <span class="symbol">$</span><span class="amount">709</span></li>
                    <li class="contest-stat">Received <a href="/logo-design/contests/car-review-company-requires-logo-36577" title="View contest">202 designs</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="winning-design-feature">
                <div class="enlarged-image-wrapper">
                    <a href="/logo-design/contests/car-review-company-requires-logo-36577">
                        <img data-src="/static/images/category-product-pages/logo-design/example1-large.png" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're losing the functionality because that functionality is applied immediately once the page has loaded. Any new elements you create--which is precisely what you're doing in the `.html()` method--do not have the lightbox functionality.

I'm not familiar enough with the lightbox library to tell you what exact code you need to execute, but I imagine that there is some function you call on a certain set of elements in order to apply the lightbox functionality to those elements. You therefore need to call that same function on the new element you're creating after creating it.

Comment: Thanks. Anyone know how to do this? This doesn't work: $('a.lightbox-trigger').lightBox({fixedNavigation:true});

Answer (score 0):

you could try the $.getScript() method on the click event to apply the js. not sure how dirty that is...